# Prove $f(x,y)=c=\ln|x|-2\ln|y|-\dfrac{1}{x^2y^2}$ is a solution for ODE $(x^2y^3+2y)dx+(2x-2x^3y^2)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE

$(x^2y^3+2y)dx+(2x-2x^3y^2)dy=0$

And I know how to solve this ODE. So, I claimed that it's a Non-Exact PDE, then I change it to Exact PDE for finding the solution.

And the solution of the ODE is

$f(x,y)=c=\ln|x|-2\ln|y|-\dfrac{1}{x^2y^2}$

And I'm pretty sure that the solution is right because I've already checked it on Wolfram Alpha.

But how I can prove this solution is the solution of the ODE? If the answer is to change it to $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ yeah I've already tried it but it seems like didn't match with the solution.
Please help me to prove this solution. Thanks.
And sorry if I have some mistakes.

Comment: Add your solution. Let's see if we can deduce the above relation from it.

Comment: The solution is f(x,y) above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\ln|x|-2\ln|y|-\frac1{x^2y^2}=c$$Differentiate with respect to $x$,$$\frac1x-\frac{2y'}y+\frac2{x^3y^2}+\frac{2y'}{x^2y^3}=0\\\implies y'=\frac{2y+x^2y^3}{2x^3y^2-2x}$$which is what we required. Thus, the solution is correct.

Comment: Oh... So it's use the implicit differentation? I don't have an idea until u did this. Thanks

Comment: @user516076 Glad to help. If it answered your question, you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

**The direct solution:**

The ODE is $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-~ \frac{x^2y^3+2y}{2x-2x^3y^2}.$$ Multiply brby $\frac{x}{y}$ in both sides to get $$\frac{d(\ln y)}{d(\ln x)}= -~ \frac{x^2y^2+2}{2-2x^2y^2}.$$ Let $x=e^X, y=e^Y$., then the ODE becomes
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=-~ \frac{e^{2(X+Y)}+2}{2(1-e^{2(X+Y)})}.$$ Now let $X+Y=V$, then $\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{dV}{dX}-1.$ The ODE changes to $$\frac{dV}{dx}=-\frac{3 e^{2V}}{2(1-e^{2V})}.$$ Separating the variables  and integratingwe get
$$-\frac{2}{3}\int \left(e^{-2V}-1\right) dV= \int dx +C\Rightarrow e^{-2V}=3X-2V +C=3X-2X-2Y +C\Rightarrow e^{-2V}=X-2Y+C$$ 
$$\Rightarrow  \frac{1}{x^2y^2}-\ln x+2 \ln y =C$$